Using arrays in Excel Chart Data-selection
I am plotting data from two different files, in a third file, to compare the relative shape of two time series (eg. stock prices). Since they have different scales the curve do not align at the starting point. I have seen things such as

={1}

in the select data inputs. One imagine that is a constant array of 1's (is it?). So I now wonder if it is possible to say add an offset or a multiplier to the whole series in the select-data input box on-the-fly to align the series; for example, something like:

='[XYZData.xlsx]Summary'!prices*{1.2}

